# Automatically windows powershell opens when I open my laptop

Tags: powershell

I have this problem going on for few days, every time I open my laptop it starts Windows Powershell automatically.It's not causing me any problem as I close it once it opens, but I am quite annoyed by it and wants to know if this is some problem or just something went bad with my settings. I am using windows 10 pro.

Comment: https://superuser.com is the site for that question. That being said if you run Autoruns from Sysinternals you should be able to tell which process spawns the shell.

Comment: If it's not an autorun thing, it could be because recent Windows 10 versions reopen programs you were running before it rebooted (and you cannot disable this feature). Is it possible your laptop is not shutting down cleanly and it thinks you had PowerShell open? Does it reopen anything else too?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler only powershell opens on startup nothing else. And my laptop shutdown cleanly too.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an autorun entry for Powershell registered on your system. Without more information, it's not possible to tell how it got there.

Programs registering themselves to start up on boot is a common symptom of malware infection, but most malware would also try to hide any visual cues, i.e. the Powershell window would be hidden.

To troubleshoot further, you can try the free utility [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) available from Microsoft. Look for any entries related to Powershell.